# Script code conflicting with width reduced image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I seem to be having an issue with a mailchimp script. When I place it in either the footer or the header anywhere within or outside the existing code in the header php or footer php, it causes my parallax hero (storefront plugin, width reduced image) to disappear. Currently, I've taken the below code out, so it looks normal like this - [image: Picture of width reduced image]

This is a copy of the code that I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-
  forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: 
  false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-
  forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us14.list-
  manage.com","uuid":"f92592d662ff169a010b1a896","lid":"d6c3aa8dcf"}) })
</script>
```

It's also worth noting that when I copy and paste other  code pointing to the embed.js, it has the same affect on my width reduced image (it still disappears) and normal HTML code is fine.

What I've tried:

1. Creating a Jquery file in the web ROOT
2. Tried other alternative script code
3. Implemented a staging site, turned off all plugins apart from parallax hero.
4. Changed Storefront theme to Twenty Seventeen theme

All the above didn't fix it. The only hunch I have is that the  code is conflicting with the rest of the image and so it may need to be  ed off.

Any help or knowledge would be much appreciated as I'm really stuck.

Errors from console: [image: Errors from console]

Comment: when you are adding this code what error you are getting?check your browser console for errors

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just added it into the description.

Comment: Just to note, the error changes depending on whether the jquery file is in the ROOT or not. Currently,  I've got a jquery file in there for the pop-up to work.

Comment: I think its to do with this: jQuery(function(a){a(".woocommerce-ordering").on("change","select.orderby",function(){a(this).closest("form").submit()}),a("input.qty:not(.product-quantity input.qty)").each(function(){var b=parseFloat(a(this).attr("min"));b>=0&&parseFloat(a(this).val())<b&&a(this).val(b)}),jQuery(".woocommerce-store-notice__dismiss-link").click(function(){Cookies.set("store_notice","hidden",{path:"/"} but I can't be sure. The 404 errors can be ignored as its a staging site.

Comment: Ok the error is down to the autoptimize plugin conflicting with jquery scripts. I seems that if I place the code mentioned outside <?php wp_footer(); ?> with the plugin already off, the image shows fine. Now testing to see if pop-up works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this with lots of testing.

Ok, so the problem was with the autoptimize plugin. I had to reinstall it to put in place the original exclusions for jquery. Turns out you need to exclude both jquery.js and jquery for it to be effective!

Also, you need to put the above code from mailchimp after php wp footer.
It worked for me and the pop-up shows without issues.

Don't forget, the jquery.js in the web root is essential for the pop-up to show.

I hope this helps someone and save them more time than it did me! It took me half a day to figure it out.